# Improving interactive component performance with constant image translation

Tags: performance, beginner, css, react.js, memory-optimization

I am making this React Component for an interactive eye that moves and tracks the user's mouse cursor wherever it goes to in the webpage. However, I faced 3 problems while doing so.

1. The eye moves as if the eye is in the middle of the webpage, so that when I place the eye somewhere other than the center of the webpage, it does not look at the cursor, only follow its movements.
2. Everytime I move my mouse in the webpage vigorously, my CPU usage rose to about 10% and my GPU rose 30%. Is this normal for interactive websites?
3. The image blurs sometimes after, when, and before moving.

Here is my Eye Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Eye.css";
import pupil from "../assets/images/pupil.png";
import eyelid from "../assets/images/eye.png";

class Eye extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this._onMouseMove);
    window.addEventListener("mouseout", this._onMouseLeave);
  }

  _onMouseMove = (e) => {
    var balls = document.getElementsByClassName("ball");

    var x = (e.clientX * 100) / window.innerWidth + "%";
    var y = (e.clientY * 100) / window.innerHeight + "%";

    console.log(e.clientX, e.clientX);

    balls[0].style.left = x;
    balls[0].style.top = y;
    balls[0].style.transform = "translate(-" + x + ",-" + y + ")";
    balls[0].style.transitionDuration = "0s";
  };

  _onMouseLeave = (e) => {
    var balls = document.getElementsByClassName("ball");

    var x = "50%";
    var y = "50%";

    balls[0].style.left = x;
    balls[0].style.top = y;
    balls[0].style.transform = "translate(-" + x + ",-" + y + ")";
    balls[0].style.transitionDuration = ".5s";
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='eyes'>
        <img className='eyelid' src={eyelid} />
        <div className='eye'>
          <div className='ball'>
            <img className='pupil' src={pupil} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Eye;
```

[The Demo Problem HERE](https://eunicocornelius.github.io/infographics/)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have deployed a demo on my gh-pages, can you take a look at it?

Comment: Yep, that'll do, thanks!

Comment: @CertainPerformance Any progress? I'm still stuck on finding a solution...